# space in classname is forcing table to be unselectable

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

when scraping the forexfactory calendar, there is a space in the `<table class="calendar__table  ">` and so nokogiri is not able to find the table.

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError (unexpected '$' after '  ')

require "nokogiri"
require "csv"
require "open-uri"
url1="https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?day=Jan5.2023"
html = URI.open(url1)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
table = doc.at('calendar__table  ')
```

The table exists in this html as see in this screenshot. So how do i scrape this table?
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So how do i scrape this table?

Comment: How is this not HTML?

Comment: Really? https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.forexfactory.com%2Fcalendar%3Fday%3DJan5.2023

Comment: I agree it's out of date according to modern standards. It is however, still HTML

Comment: I don't buy it. The phrase `<div    ">` isn't valid in any version of HTML since HTML was invented.

Comment: Nokogiri accepts it and throws on OP's query, not at parse time. Yes, an HTML validator vomits on the page, and yes, it's horrible. But one of the shining advantages to HTML is its recoverability. You can give a web browser a pile of dog poop and it will try to make something coherent out of it. And in my experience, Nokogiri's HTML parser (as opposed to its XML parser, which is strictly adherent to the standard) is fairly fault-tolerant about things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Node#at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) takes either a CSS selector or an XPath string. Since you're trying to match a CSS class, you should use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

```
table = doc.at('.calendar__table')
```

For completeness, you can also do it with XPath, but you have to tell XPath about the spaces in the `class` in that case, since it's viewing the document as raw XML, not as HTML with CSS classes.

```
table = doc.at('//*[@class="calendar__table  "]')
```